# Hydrolyse Phosphonate diester to free phosphonic acid under relatively mild conditions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, synthesis, hydrolysis, organophosphorus-compounds

I want to hydrolyse a phosphonic acid diethylester to the corresponding free phosphonic acid. In the literature, it is described, that usually strongly basic or acidic conditions are utilized to achieve this.

*The Hydrolysis of Phosphinates and Phosphonates: A Review*.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8150351/

[image]

Alternatively one can utilize ester cleavage by TMSBr and water workup.

In my case, however, multiple complications occur. R is a complex substituent, which will not tolerate too acidic conditions. In addition, when performing a reaction under basic conditions, the problem is, that base like NaOH or KOH would introduce a very polar species to the mixture in which the product can not separated off easyly from the free phosphonic acid that would be for sure also very polar. (I know, that one possible way get rid of the excess would be the utilization of ion exchange, but from my experience  this is an extremely time consuming process when your product as well your impurities are UV inactive.) In addition to that, reaction control would be problematic due to the fact, that the product is likely to co-elute with the base, therefore the reliable reaction control by LCMS, would be problematic, also because the product is not carrying UV active groups. I am therefore wondering if there are possible other strategies to transform the diester into the acid preferably in a fashion, that does not create a problematic purification situation and work in comparison to TMSBr with milder conditions that are not too acidic.

Comment: Do you have any control over what the ester group is? Can you make it something other than Et/Me?

Comment: The Et group is a consequence of the precursor used in the previous step, because it contains it. I thing however, it would be possible to exchange Et to a different group before hydrolysis. I did however not try this yet and Methyl is however the only one that should hydrolyse more readily.

Comment: I am wondering, if it would not be an idea worth testing to just try a strong organic base like DBU, DBN or a similar one in water, water/methanol mixture. And to see if the product will appear. I would also think to apply microwave conditions could be an good idea to counteract the weaker base's reaction speed in comparison to alkaline bases. In addition, if lucky, an easy DCM water extraction would be enough, to remove the excess base.

Comment: Is it possible to swap the phosphonate alkyl group for something that could be removed under entirely different conditions? Dibenzyl phosphonate that could be removed by hydrogenation or diallyl with Pd+Nucleophile?

Comment: How about a resin-bound strong organic base?

Comment: Resin bound strong organic bases will likely permanently bind to the final product. Observed this on strong anionic exchangers in comparison to weak anion exchangers.

Comment: would your substrate stand hydrogenation?

Comment: I did not try hydrogenation out yet. Coming back to the benzyl alcohol protection: Introducing this to the precursor Is not so easy however. Transesterrication of ethyl to benzyl alcohol is problematic because it can not be evaporated and high excess is usually used for transesterrication. Maybe a workaround would be to do first all the reactions that form R and than try to replace ethyl by benzyl alcohol, because due to a charge of the product, it could be seperated off from  by anion exchange at this point. But I am not sure if transesterrication of ethyl to benzyl would be easy.

Comment: Maybe cyanoethyl protection may also be a way to achieve the free phosphonic acid by soft basic conditions. It is usually cleaved by ammonia or triethylamine. I would need to test, if this group would survive the conditions that deliver the R group.

Comment: How many steps back do you have to go to change the starting phosphonate?

Comment: The phosphonate utilized 2 steps back determines the structure I want to hydrolyse to the phosphonic acid. The first reaction undergoes basic conditions, the second one water free acidic.

Comment: Can you run that step with dibenzyl phosphonate instead of diethyl? You probably have to make it from methyl phosphonic dichloride, as I don't think it is commecially available

Comment: I think this would definitely work. The benzyl alcohol group should stay intact during the acidic key reaction step that would form the protected ester and even be better than ethyl in terms of stability. However the trouble would be an access route to the correct phosphonate that contains the benzyl alcohol residues and a third needed functionality. I imagine a route starting from dibenzyl phosphite which is affordable to form the necessary building block in 2 subsequent reactions. This would be manageable as well because these 2 reactions would have fairly good yield.

Comment: ...I would however need to think and validate, that this additional effort is really unavoidable, if hydrolysis would be achievable by fairly soft conditions I would not be pushed to invest the extra time for these steps. Also, the product must be stable against hydrogenation which I don't know yet, so trying this would be a little bit of a gamble, but it's definitely an interesting thought if the other strategies will not lead to success, especially because Pd/Charcoal should be easy to be seperated off.

Comment: @Waylander I checked the dibenzyl idea as a precursor. It seems that I purified the correct structure, but until know it did not react in the predicted way. I will try different conditions to check again on this, but the deprotection step indeed works fast and completely The tlc spot at RF- 0.5 dissapears after Pd/C treatment and a new baseline spot appears.